# Visual Studio won't let me add a break point unless there's a comment on the line above

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

Visual Studio won't let me add a break point unless there's a comment on the line above.
It started a couple of weeks ago, very annoying.
I get a message in the status bar "A breakpoint cannot be inserted at this point".
To solve it I have to add a comment in the line above and then add the breakpoint to the comment line and then it works. It has to be a comment putting a new line of code in doesn't work.
I'm using VS2017 15.3.5.

Has anyone else experienced this and have a solution.

Comment: Try creating a new project and moving all source files to it. See if problem is also "moved" to new project.

Comment: @benb, Which kind of app did you create? Could you share the main code as a sample? If you create a simple app, how about the result? Please also delete .suo file in your project folder, and then re-open it, clean and build your solution, add the breakpoint again. Of course, if you have other VS Environment, please also test it using the same sample.

Comment: Thanks. It's a standard .net project. I'm not permitted to show the code. I've copied out some of the code into a new project and it works fine. It's a shared project pulled down from SVN and no-one else has the issue. I'll have to keep digging.

Comment: @benb, Maybe it was the project file issue, if possible, just take backup for your project, and then create a blank solution, add all project files to this blank solution, clean and rebuild your solution, view the result.  In addition, the latest VS2017 would be the 15.4.1 version. Please also update your VS to latest version. View the result.

Comment: I did an update but that failed so I reinstalled VS (it's now 15.4.1), now it works fine. Not sure what happened there but all seems to be well now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @benb, Maybe it was related to certain debugging package load, anyway, since it works well now, you could post it as the answer, and than mark it as the answer. So this case could be closed. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue the only thing I could do in the end was re-install Visual Studio which solved the problem. Hopefully if anyone hits this problem in the future they'll be able to find a less drastic course of action.

Thanks everyone for your help.
B